Is it possible to pass "props" in JSF custom components?
I recently landed on a project using JavaServer Faces for the FE side, with XHTML pages.
There's a lot of duplicated code, and studying this technology I found out that is possible to create custom components and reuse it (as JSF is meant to be), but I can't find any tutorial or documentation about how to pass properties value (basicaly like using props in React), which will cut out almost the 80% of the entire code base.
For example: I would like to reuse a component with differents backing beans, in different pages of course.
Does anyone have a cue of where do I can find something to better learn from or knows how I can achieve that?

Your question is quite broad and it isn't terribly clear whether you correctly understood/used the term "custom components". In any case, is this potential duplicate helpful in order to get started with learning the proper terminology and seeing some real world examples? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6822000

You actually been so helpful. Sorry for the mispelled and confusing question.

Okay. I guess you just need an include/template or tagfile or composite. You can of course plainly pass "whole beans" (instead of e.g. multiple strings) via a single ui:param or tag attribute or cc:attribute. Sufficient examples linked in abovelinked duplicate.
